# Aggregate 1D arrays of various lengths into 2D array

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have 4 subqueries returning zero+ rows of SMALLINT[] of length 1+.

I would like to aggregate all of the subquery results into a single row of SMALLINT[][].

Because the arrays are of differing lengths I am unsure of how to roll them up?  Using the 9.5 ARRAY_AGG returns "cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality".

Answer (score 2):

You could pad `array` with `NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col smallint[]);

INSERT INTO tab(col) 
VALUES ('{1}'), ('{1,2}'), ('{1,2,3}'), ('{}');

SELECT array_agg(
          array_cat(
            col,
            array_fill(NULL::smallint, ARRAY[l-COALESCE(array_length(col, 1),0)])
          )
       ) AS result
FROM tab;
,LATERAL (SELECT MAX(array_length(col,1)) AS l
          FROM tab) s
```

Output:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                       result                        ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ {{1,NULL,NULL},{1,2,NULL},{1,2,3},{NULL,NULL,NULL}} ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to prepare this creative answer.  I should have specified that I was seeking a "compact" 2D response without NULL values.  I suppose it isn't the end of the world to run 4 queries and roll them up in application logic but I'm frankly shocked that this can't be done with pure Postgres.