# Array_agg integer arrays of different lengths in postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to aggregate integer arrays that have different lengths.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596539/aggregate-1d-arrays-of-various-lengths-into-2d-array) pads with nulls and I am trying to incorporate it into my query.

Here is my data:

```
id   | col
-----+---------
1    | {5,3}
1    | {6,4}
2    | {3}
2    | {2,3}
```

Here is my desired result

```
    id   | col
    -----+---------
    1    | {{5,3},{6,4}}
    2    | {{3,NULL},{2,3}}
```

See [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0f4618e83860a05a8dbf86788bf6df0e)

This is my current query, which aggregrates by id but it outputs duplicates. This is my first time using `LATERAL` function so don't know if this is right approach.

```
SELECT 
array_agg(
          array_cat(
            col,
            array_fill(NULL::smallint, ARRAY[lat-COALESCE(array_length(col, 1),0)])
          )
       ) AS result
,tab.id
FROM tab
,LATERAL (SELECT id,MAX(array_length(col,1)) AS lat
          FROM tab GROUP BY id) s
GROUP BY tab.id
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a slightly different approach:

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(col, 1) < max_length THEN (col || ARRAY_FILL(NULL::SMALLINT, ARRAY[max_length]))[1:max_length] ELSE col END) AS result
FROM tab, (SELECT MAX(ARRAY_LENGTH(col, 1)) AS max_length FROM tab) m
GROUP BY id
```

If the length is less than the max array length, append an array of max length, then take a "slice" of max length; as a result it works like `OVERLAY` does for strings.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=56b135d87dd919e84ca43daeaf2b081c

Or slightly differently:

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(col, 1) < max_length THEN col || ARRAY_FILL(NULL::SMALLINT, ARRAY[max_length - ARRAY_LENGTH(col, 1)]) ELSE col END) AS result
FROM tab, (SELECT MAX(ARRAY_LENGTH(col, 1)) AS max_length FROM tab) m
GROUP BY id
```

Only add the required number of NULLs to the array.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=22e86b81131a68844206338bf4428dab